# Break on next action in Visual Studio 2010 c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have a huge program and I'm trying to debug it in VS2010. What I'd like to say is break on the first successfully matched message map item, where ever it is in the code, once I activate this option. I don't know if this is possible but it would be very helpful as there are too many items to individually put a break point on. I think this would be effectively; stop on next line in the code base.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `Condition` on a `Breakpoint`. Right-click on the `Breakpoint` and then you can add a `Condition`. You can control whether the `Breakpoint` breaks if the condition `Is true` or `Has changed`.

Another useful tool to debug are "memory breakpoints". From the `Breakpoints` window, click `New > New Data Breakpoint` and provide the address and size you want to monitor, as soon as a change is made to this memory, it will break into the debugger.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'm afraid I'm utterly clueless as where to put the  first break in the code and don't know the memory location.

Comment: Since you want the "first item" to match an item, a memory breakpoint probably is not what you're looking for. Don't you have a method that's called when a message is matched? don't you have some boolean that stores a `is_matched` or something that you could break on?

Comment: if you don't have such code, write it in.  there's nothing wrong with adding some code to help you diagnose issues... you can always remove it later...

Comment: Problem is I have no idea in the code where to put that code. The whole project is 100'sKLOC.

Comment: Well, there must be the "match" check somewhere?  that would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [DebugBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function inside your source code.